# accessing iphone file system and copy file

Tags: ios, cross-platform

I'd like to know way to  access iphones file system and copy files to app's documents programmatically on windows platform. I know there are several programs accoplish this goal [here](http://dottech.org/tipsntricks/18890/four-ways-to-access-your-idevices-iphoneipadipod-touch-file-system-from-your-computer/) . Also it shouldn't be against the apple licence.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the very article you link to states:

> First of all you need have a jailbroken device.

With a device that is not jailbroken, you can not access the filesystem directly.

Any form of jailbreaking breaks Apple's EULA. Thus what you request can't be done.